# C++ template incomprehensible behaviour

Tags: c++, templates

First of all - this code is bad, I know it, it's made for experimenting with templates, but I sincerely don't know how/why it works as it shows.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class Container {
public:
    Container() { 
        std::cout << "Container()" << std::endl;
    }
    Container(const Container& other){
        std::cout << "Container(const Container& other)" << std::endl;
    }
    template <typename A>
    Container(const A& other) {
        std::cout << "Container(const A& other)" << std::endl;
    }
    Container(const std::vector<int>& other) { 
        std::cout << "Container(const std::vector<int>& other)" << std::endl;
    }
    ~Container() { 
        std::cout << "~Container()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    Container<int> c1;
    Container<int> c2(c1);
    Container<int> c3(std::vector<int>());
    Container<int> c4();
    Container<int> c3(std::string());

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Container()
Container(const Container& other)
Container()
~Container()
~Container()
~Container()
```

The questions are:

1. it compiles! (with -Wall, -Wextra only show unused other parameter) Why?
2. it runs! (I might expect some UB, but I don't know the genesis). Why?

What's happening here? Why c3 variable(s) seem to be totally ignored? I get the slight idea, that maybe it can't expand the templates, but why wouldn't it fail during compile time?

Compiler: gcc version 4.8.1

Comment: `c3`, `c4` and `c5` aren't variables, they're functions, due to the [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: With c4, true. I've missed that, but it was put only as filling. There is no c5.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice the last one is `c3` as well. Still, it's just another overload of the first `c3` function.

Comment: @sth explaining, why it's a "valid C++ code" would suffice.

Comment: @zoska There *should be* a `c5` :) You're redefining `c3` (it compiles because they're considered as function overloads)

Comment: "Running" is compatible with "undefined behaviour". Undefined code often goes undetected for a considerable time.

Comment: @zoska: It just wasn't obvious what the potential problem was, since it's easy to miss that `c3` is declared twice in all that code. If you had pointed to that fact specifically it would have been more clear what you were confused about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both `c3` variables are really function declarations (as Angew points out in a comment) you end up declaring overloaded functions.

You declare one overload that takes a `std::vector<int>()` parameter and one that takes a `std::string()` parameter. These two overloads don't conflict and the code compiles.

Comment: Why it's not taken as Container constructors?

Comment: @zoska Most vexing parse. Follow the link in my comment

Comment: And I was thinking about testing this with local variables (not created inside 'contructor' invocation), but somehow abandoned this idea... Damn.

Answer (score 1):

As said before: c3, c4 and c5 are function declarations,but noone says how to fix it.

```
Container<int> c3((std::vector<int>())); // add parentheses to clarify it's not a function declaration
Container<int> c4; // remove parentheses
Container<int> c3((std::string())); // add parentheses
```

Comment: or use `c3{std::vector<int>()};` `c4{};` with C++11.